# separar array e fazer consulta no bd

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

tenho uma variável `$servicos` que recebe a lista de serviços cadastrados no BD através desse código.

```
$query_servicos = "SELECT * FROM servicos ORDER BY nome ASC";
$result_servicos = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_servicos);
$servicos = array();
while ($linhas_servicos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_servicos)){
$servicos[] = $linhas_servicos['nome'];
}
$servicos = implode( ' ', $servicos);
```

preciso separar os dados pra listalos e realizar uma consulta.

```
$buscatotala = "SELECT * FROM dia WHERE dia='$datec' AND func='Alex' AND servicos LIKE '%$servicos%'";
$resultado_totala = mysqli_query($conectar, $buscatotala);
$totala = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_totala);

// Preciso que essa parte se repita, preenchendo a tabela com os dados do funcionário.                                                 
echo "
     <tr>
         <td>".$servicos[]."</td>
         <td>";
             if ($totala != '0'){
             echo "<font color='red'>";
             }
         echo $totala."</font></td>
     </tr>";
```

assim poderia aliviar o código, por que não repetiria a consulta que lista os serviços, nos próximos funcionários.

EX: PRÓXIMO FUNCIONÁRIO:

```
$buscatotali = "SELECT * FROM dia WHERE dia='$datec' AND func='Italo' AND servicos LIKE '%$servicos%'";
$resultado_totali = mysqli_query($conectar, $buscatotali);
$totali = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_totali);

echo "
     <tr>
         <td>".$servicos[]."</td>
         <td>";
             if ($totali != '0'){
             echo "<font color='red'>";
             }
         echo $totali."</font></td>
     </tr>";
```

código inteiro para um funcionário (estou repetindo o mesmo código para os outros funcionários apenas trocando a terminação das $ com a letra inicial correspondente ao funcionário):

```
<div class="accrodion-regular">
<div id="accordion3">
<div class="card my-0">
   <div class="card-header1" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
         <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         <span class="fas mr-3 fa-angle-down"></span>Serviços
         </button>
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion3" style="">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table no-wrap p-table">
               <tbody>
                  <?php
         $query_listserva = "SELECT * FROM servicos ORDER BY nome ASC";
         $result_listserva = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_listserva);
                     while ($linhas_listserva = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_listserva)){
                     $servicosa = $linhas_listserva['nome'];
                     $buscatotala = "SELECT * FROM dia WHERE dia='$datec' AND func='Alex' AND servicos LIKE '%$servicosa%'";
                     $resultado_totala = mysqli_query($conectar, $buscatotala);
                     $totala = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_totala);

                     echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>".$servicosa."</td>
                            <td>";
                                if ($totala != '0'){
                                echo "<font color='red'>";
                                }
                            echo $totala."</font></td>
                        </tr>";
                     }
                  ?>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, tem uma maneira de utilizar pela própria consulta *MySQLi*, pois você apenas consulta e lista a tabela `servicos` para obter o resultado `nome`. Sendo assim podemos simplificar seu código transformando a consulta `servicos` em um `WHERE` dentro da própria consulta. Veja o exemplo:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['userservico'])) {
    $userServ = $_POST['userservico'];
    $datec = $_POST['dateserv'];
    $servico = $_POST['servico'];

    $conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testes");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $queryGeral = "SELECT serv.nome, d.dia, d.func, d.servicos FROM servicos AS serv LEFT JOIN dia AS d ON d.func = '" . $userServ . "' WHERE d.dia = '" . $datec . "' AND d.servicos LIKE '%" . $servico . "%' ORDER BY serv.nome ASC";

    $resultGeral = mysqli_query($conectar, $queryGeral);
    $totali = mysqli_num_rows($resultGeral);
    $servicos = array();
    while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultGeral)){
        $servicos[] = $linhas['nome'];
    }

    $servicos = implode(' ', $servicos);
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>".$servicos."</td>
    <td>";
    if ($totali != '0'){
        echo "<font color='red'>";
    }
    echo $totali."</font></td>
    </tr>";
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    Nome Funcionario:<br>
    <input type="text" name="userservico"><br><br>
    Dia:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dateserv"><br><br>
    Servico:<br>
    <input type="text" name="servico"><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Consultar</button>
</form>
```

Basicamente ficaria dessa maneira ai, não pude ter o meio de testar o código, sendo assim pode haver alguma redundância no código, mas basicamente é isto que você irá fazer (Sendo a parte de código "suja", rápida e mais simples de você entender). Caso haja algum problema, só comentar que damos um jeito de arrumar o código! :)

Comment: aloha Rapha, show mas a ideia era retornar os dados dos 3 funcionários ao mesmo tempo em div's diferentes...

Comment: Então deixa eu ver se entendi, eu irei inserir quais dados na pesquisa para que possa se obter o resultado? Só para saber para que eu possa fazer a modificação no código.

Comment: editei com o código completo, não há pesquisa, a página é um "Dashboard" e preciso trazer os dados de cada funcionário, ao mesmo tempo, na mesma página. (div "Alex", div "Italo", div "Naldo"...) o que estou fazendo é repetir todo o código alterando o func=' ' com o nome de cada um e as terminações das $ com a inicial do funcionário.

Comment: isso que está pesando, até o momento a página já faz 4 consultas que retornam a lista de serviços. a ideia é fazer apenas 1 e usar pra buscar os dados de cada um dos funcionários.

Comment: Entendi, então é realmente apenas a consulta através da query mesmo né? Nada de consultas através de formulários...

Comment: isso, apenas a Query pra mostrar os dados